# Custom middlewear for a bot made with ms bot composer(node js)

Tags: botframework, middleware

I want to write a custom middleware for my bot made with ms bot framework composer, to get the time stamp for each message user sent? Any help?

I am expecting to be able to integrate the custom middlewear with the bot which will log the time stamp for each user message

Answer (score 0):

Each activity exchanged between bots and users already has a timestamp in it. These timestamps are already logged when you enable Application Insights. You do not need to build custom middleware to log them.

Comment: I need the timestamp to calculate the user inactivity period, which I can't do with the pre-built middleware, can you help me with that? Thanks for answering.

Comment: In your bot code, you can read the timestamp from the context. You can then use this value to compare against the timestamp you stored from the user's last message. Here's the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) on middleware.

Comment: I have to check if the user inactivity period exceeds a limit upon receiving each message from the user and run a dialog if so. How can I implement that in a bot composed in bot composer(node.js)?